# Why are you not allowed to bind a rvalue reference to a non const reference but you are allowed to call non const member functions on one

Tags: c++, reference

The following are roughly equivalent in terms of being dangerous but the second 2 are disallowed by the language yet the first one isn't.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    // allowed
    std::vector<int>().swap(v);

    // not allowed
    v.swap(std::vector<int>());

    // not allowed
    std::swap(std::vector<int>(), v);
}
```

I know Visual Studio lets all these through as a compiler extension and I'm ignoring that for this question.

I'm not actually arguing that the first one be disallowed - I'd actually prefer the second 2 be allowed (there are places where this makes code more elegant and normally when C++ lets you do some thing which may be dangerous but could be benefical it lets it through) but it seems weird that there is a difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function arguments are subject to type conversions, which create a temporary *rvalue*. This would give confusing results if the function were passed a non-const reference to that temporary, when you expect it modify the argument. This potential confusion is a justification for not allowing temporaries to bind to non-const *lvalue* references.

There is no corresponding confusion for other reference types; `const` references leave the object unmodified as expected, and *rvalue* references are specifically intended to bind to *rvalues*. Neither does the issue arise for member functions, since type conversions aren't applied to the object being called on.