# How to pass an rvalue as a reference argument to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, rvalue

I have a function that takes the reference of an object. In one particular call instance, I don't care how the function process that particular object. Hence I wish I could avoid creating that object in the main function.

The code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>

void myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int> &mp);

int main() {
  myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int>());
  return 0;
}

void myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int> &mp) {
  printf("%d\n",mp.size());
  printf("Hello world.\n");
}
```

The bottom line is: I don't want to declare and initialize an `unordered_map<int,int>` object in the main function. This version of the code reports:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::unordered_map&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::unordered_map’

I also tried `const_cast<>` and `std::move`, but neither works.

The error can be removed if we change the API to:

```
void myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int> &&mp)
```

The problem is that the API is shared among multiple files, and we really don't want to change it. Given the API of `myFunc` has to be fixed, how can I modify `main()` such that I don't need to explicitly create an object?

--------------------------edit------------------------

Another way to work around is to write a wrapping function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>

void myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int> &mp);
void UglyWorkAround(std::unordered_map<int,int> &&mp);

int main() {
  UglyWorkAround(std::unordered_map<int,int>());
  return 0;
}

void UglyWorkAround(std::unordered_map<int,int> &&mp) {
  myFunc(mp);
}

void myFunc(std::unordered_map<int,int> &mp) {
  printf("%d\n",mp.size());
  printf("Hello world.\n");
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself why you need a non-const reference in that function.

Comment: Then ask yourself, if the object is about to expire, does it make sense to even do those operations...

Comment: You either pass a `&&` or a `const&` depending on your purpose. You cannot (and shouldn't even if you could) pass a non-const reference to a temporary.

Comment: @Commenters. It makes sense and you do. Just because it doesn't make sense in a bunch of cases doesn't mean there arent cases where it entirely legitimate. And c++ allows you to shoot yourself in the foot in a lot of other ways. The real reason its not allowed is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231626/why-are-you-not-allowed-to-bind-a-rvalue-reference-to-a-non-const-reference-but

Comment: A place where it makes sense consider the function `void f(Workspace& w);` where you can pass in a scratch space that the function uses. You'd normally want to use a longe lived scratch spave for some reasons, but calling `f(Workspace())` is entirely legit and useful.

Comment: @MikeVine I would argue that would warrant passing the argument *by value* which would allow for the variable to exist only within the scope of the function

Comment: @MikeVine Unclear what you are talking about. C++ doesn't allow binding non-const lvalue references to rvalues.

Comment: @CoryKramer but that would preclude passing in references to longer lived scratch spaces. Yes you could work round this (like you can work round a lot of things) but that doesn't mean its not useful anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanze Yes it doesn't but not for the reasons given here. See my link - its real use is to stop unnecessary and bad conversions not 'well you lose the changes'. Did you read my first link?

Comment: @juanchopanza In other calling instance, the object might need to be modified. But in this instance, I don't care if it is modified.

Comment: I'm left wondering what actual runtime impact this has. I'm guessing negligible.

Comment: @user3813057 I was giving you a hint to help you read the error message and fix your code.

Comment: @user3813057 Then provide a `const&` overload

Comment: @MikeVine Your link is interesting, but has nothing to do with the question here. And more importantly, the reason in that answer doesn't make too much sense. C++ always has many detailed rules for special cases, if those standard committee people want, the conversion can be disabled in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desire to avoid writing a definition for a `std::unordered_map<int, int>` object does not appear to be founded upon any legitimate concerns. However, since that's what you asked, here's a way to do it:

```
using M = std::unordered_map<int, int>;
myFunc(const_cast<M&>(static_cast<const M&>(M())));
```

Comment: @RyanHaining In the case discussed in the question you have linked, yes. In the case of a class type, no.

Comment: after a bunch of looking around, I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, C++ doesn't allow you to pass in a temporary for a non-const lvalue reference. Your proposed solution with an rvalue reference would break your other uses.

What I would suggest for this case (which may not work depending on your actual use) would be to add a `myFunc` overload:

```
void myFunc() {
  std::unordered_map<int,int> m{};
  myFunc(m);
}
```

And then change your main to call

```
int main() {
  myFunc();
}
```